# http to https node proxy

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

I would like to know the easiest way to set up a proxy where I can make HTTP requests in (i.e.) `localhost:8011` and the proxy makes a HTTPS request in `localhost:443` (the HTTPS answer from the server should be translated to HTTP by the proxy as well)

I'm using node.js

I've tried `http-proxy` like this:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var options = {
  changeOrigin: true,
  target: {
      https: true
  }
}

httpProxy.createServer(443, 'localhost', options).listen(8011);
```

I have also tried this:

```
httpProxy.createProxyServer({   
    target: {
        host:'https://development.beigebracht.com',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        https: true,   
    } 
}).listen(port);
```

But when I'm trying to connect I'm getting this error

```
/Users/adrian/Development/beigebracht-v2/app/webroot/node_modules/http-proxy/lib/http-proxy/passes/web-incoming.js:103
    var proxyReq = (options.target.protocol === 'https:' ? https : http).reque
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
```

I would like to do it with node, but, other solutions can be valid.
(The proxy will be used in localhost just with testing purposes so security is not a problem)

Comment: Currently in this process myself as well. Are you sure about target being an object? It seems like it should just be the url string?

Answer (score 0):

I needed a HTTP->HTTPS node proxy for unit testing. What I ended up doing was creating the HTTP proxy and then have it listen for and handle the `connect` event. When the server receives the CONNECT request, it sets up a tunnel to the HTTPS target URL and forwards all packets from the client socket to the target socket and vice versa.

Sample code:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var net = require('net');
var url = require('url');

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3002
};

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

proxy.http = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var target = url.parse(req.url);

    // The `path` attribute would cause problems later.
    target.path = undefined;

    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: target
    });

}).listen(options.port, options.host);

// This allows the HTTP proxy server to handle CONNECT requests.
proxy.http.on('connect', function connectTunnel(req, cltSocket, head) {

    // Bind local address of proxy server.
    var srvSocket = new net.Socket({
        handle: net._createServerHandle(options.host)
    });

    // Connect to an origin server.
    var srvUrl = url.parse('http://' + req.url);

    srvSocket.connect(srvUrl.port, srvUrl.hostname, function() {
        cltSocket.write(
            'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established\r\n' +
            'Proxy-agent: Node.js-Proxy\r\n' +
            '\r\n'
        );
        srvSocket.write(head);
        srvSocket.pipe(cltSocket);
        cltSocket.pipe(srvSocket);
    });
});
```